# Difference between << and >> when used with - in bash

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection

It's probably a bit specific, as something I encountered when looking at the scripts of a rpm package. The initial package had:

```
rpm --import - << EOF
GPG
KEY
HERE
EOF
```

This failed with the following error: -: import read failed(0).

Package was modified and now installs without issues with the following:

```
echo "GPG
KEY
HERE" >> rpm --import -
```

I don't understand why the first one fails and not the second. Also, would it be possible to have

```
echo "GPG
KEY
HERE" | rpm --import -
```

As an option?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: the one with `>> rpm` should create a _file_ called `rpm`, not call `rpm` as a program at all. So.. I suppose it might work, in the sense of not getting an error from any individual step. It just might not do what it's supposed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example treats the text between `EOF` instances as a double-quoted string that has variable interpolation (i.e. all variables, commands, and expressions beginning with `$` or in paired backticks are evaluated and expanded). This is fed as *stdin* to the `rpm` command.

Your second instance appends these three lines (also with variable interpolation):

```
GPG
KEY
HERE --import -
```

to the file `rpm` in the current directory. Notice specifically that *it does not run the `rpm` command*.

Your third option writes the three lines (again with variable interpolation):

```
GPG
KEY
HERE
```

as the *stdin* for the command `rpm --import -`

In all cases you can prevent expansion and interpolation of variables by using single quotes around the string instead of ndouble quotes or none (in the first case, you'd use `<<'EOF'`).

Also be aware that it seems `rpm` does not use `-` as a marker to read from *stdin*, so none of the options will do what you seem to want. You're going to need to write the GPG key to a file or use the `<( echo... )` construct in place of `-`.

Comment: Another curious thing is how rpm's `--import -` really works. I tried to look for the manuals, but basically all I found was mentions of `--import PUBKEY`, where they didn't even spell out that it's a filename. No mention of `-` as meaning stdin. And I don't have RH systems to check on, except an ancient one where `rpm --import -` didn't even bother to try to read from a terminal or a pipe, it just `fstat()`'d the fd and only read it if referred to a file... Also I wondered why a package install should need to add pubkeys to the package manager (shouldn't one have the keys before installing?)

Comment: @ilkkachu you've investigated the detail more than I have; I just looked at the shell syntax. You've some really strange discoveries there. And I've no answer for any of them :-)

Comment: yeah, I was kinda hoping you'd have more experience on RH / rpm than I do. :)

Comment: Sorry, no. I run Debian

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. In the 2nd option, which would --import - be included into the "rpm" file? I have tested it and indeed it is present in the file alongside the signature.

Comment: @ikkachu, the package was downloaded from the vendor's site. I try to always cross-check things so I contacted them to get gpg key + sha sum and imported the gpg key myself as I set up rpm to check for gpgkey even for offline installs. However I suppose some people don't add the gpg key first and so post-install script in the rpm package imports it to avoid dnf asking for import during the update process. As said, I'm a bit paranoid with packages which I install from outside of the normal repo and extract the rpm / scripts, etc. to inspect them which is how I came across this

Comment: And actually, the 3rd option also gives error: -: import read failed(0) so I guess that the cause of the issue in the first place is just that rpm does not read from standard and so this needs to be a file imported. From a quick search, this seems to work with apt-key which may explain why it was written this way